# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity error mapping JSON to SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Copy Activity that is using a REST request to elastic search as the Source and attempting to map the response to a SQL table as the Sink. Everything works fine except when it attempts to map the `data` field that contains the dynamic JSON. I get the following error:

> {
>       "errorCode": "2200",
>       "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorUnsupportedHierarchicalComplexValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The retrieved type of data JObject with value {\"name\":\"department\"} is not supported yet, please either remove the targeted column or enable skip incompatible row to skip them.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
>       "failureType": "UserError",
>       "target": "CopyContents_Paged",
>       "details": []
>   }

Here's an example of my mapping configuration:

```
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "mappings": [
        {
            "source": {
                "path": "['_source']['id']"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "ContentItemId",
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "path": "['_source']['status']"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "Status",
                "type": "Int32"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "path": "['_source']['data']"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "Data",
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    ],
    "collectionReference": "$['hits']['hits']"
}
```

The JSON in the `data` object is dynamic so I'm unable to do an explicit mapping for the nested fields within it. That's why I'm trying to just store the entire JSON object under `data` in a column of a SQL table.

How can I adjust my mapping configuration to allow this to work properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I posted this question on the MSDN forums and I was told that if you are using a tabular sink you can set this option `"mapComplexValuesToString": true` and it should allow complex JSON properties to get mapped correctly. This resolved my ADF copy activity issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem a few days ago. You need to convert your JSON object to a Json String. It will solve your mapping problem (UserErrorUnsupportedHierarchicalComplexValue).

Try it and tell me if also resolves your error.

Comment: Are you saying to add some kind of conversion to the mapping configuration?

Comment: Yes, don't know the type of language that you are using to collect the data from the source. But for example if you are using c# can do something like this:
string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject)

Comment: Or you can to a direct cast in the mapping configuration as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732768/cast-values-to-string-in-json-path-expression-in-azure-data-factory-copy-activit

Comment: The source is just a POST elastic search query. I don't think you are able to do any kind of conversion when querying elastic search. The only valid  Content-Type header is ```application/json```. So I'm not sure a conversion like that is possible with this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do a direct cast in the path field. It errors if you try to do something like ```"source": {
                "path": "@string(['_source']['data'])"
            }```

Comment: you aren't using DF v2?

Comment: Yeah I am. That example you posted of the direct cast was in a ```value``` field not a ```path``` field so I'm guessing that's the issue.

Comment: maybe if you use a copy activity tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool it call help you to cast the information to avoid that error. Or by previous create the dataset to source of mapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json

Comment: I did try the copy data tool and it resulted in the same error. I also created the dataset as JSON format but it resulted in the same error also. Thank you for those suggestions.

Comment: Ok, sorry can help you, if I remender some other solution will tell you.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I posted the solution above that I received from the MSDN team in case you were curious.